# Looking for a persistent database for an Electron app that's NOT in-memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, electron, nosql

I'm looking for a persistent database -- preferably a document database like MongoDB -- for an Electron application I'm working on. I looked at NeDB, but found out that it keeps a copy of the database in memory at all times -- and this won't work for me because I'm expecting an extremely large number of records, and as far as I know it's not really possible to simply bundle MongoDB with an Electron application.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: I'm trying to find something where I can directly insert and query JSON documents like Mongo -- SQLite is on my mind, but it's a last resort if I can't find anything else. @Ryan

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/petersirka/nosql it's part of Total.js framework but can be used separately. I use it myself for a few apps and it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me you should use LinvoDB because they are best with large objects also they are not effected by large db size and uses mongodb queries for CRUD operation.

I think its best for your application as you were looking for a kind of db that does not persist in the memory.It also does not scan whole db whenever query is fired.

There is also one more db option realm which is the best db according to me and it is released few days back.

please refer: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/262

Cheers :)

Comment: I decided on LinvoDB with LevelDown as a backend. Thanks!